# get element in array based on element's attributes

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a simple question regarding how to extract elements from array based on their attribute(s).

I have an array of objects :

```
obj_array = [obj1,obj2,obj3........]
```

each objects has an attribute called 'type' which returns an object. So,

```
object1.type = type1
object2.type = type3
object3.type = type8
object4.type = type1
...
```

I would like to find and extract a list of objects in `obj_array` that is typed by 'type1' and store them in an array. The resulting array should look like this:

`type1_array = [object1,object4]`

Here is my solution using a loop:

```
type1_array = []
obj_array.each do |e|
   if e.type == type1
      type1_array << e
   end
end
```

Is there a short way to do this in Ruby without having to loop through every elements in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ruby's selected method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select)  is probably what you're looking for.

```
obj_array.select { |obj| obj.type == type1 }
```

Obviously make sure you define `type1`.

Comment: This won't work. Your code will `return` from the enclosing method as soon as the block is executed the first time, i.e. at the very first element of the array.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks for catching that.  I've been doing too much javascript lately :)